# Inserting filenames into tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying insert a row per image that is uploaded through the script I've created to act as a gallery although I'm having some issues actually inserting image names into the table. I've managed to post the gallery ID, now I need to do the same as for the image name. I've tried messing around with different methods such as using variables etc to make no difference. I'm not too sure how I'd do this successfully :S.

```
$file = ($_FILES['file']['name']);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "../galleries/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $sql="INSERT INTO images (url, gallery)
    VALUES
  ('$file','$id')";
```

Thanks - Josh

Comment: Where is `$id` defined?  What errors are you getting? Have you tried running your SQL query directly against the database (i.e. not in PHP) to see what happens?

Comment: The $id is defined through a parameter from the url. That doesn't seem to be the issue though, that's working prefectly. Just seems to be the filename that has me stumped :S - It appears as Array in the url column or doesn't create a row at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `()` here?

```
$file = ($__FILES['file']['name']);
```

You need to remove the `()` if you want anything other than a boolean as the value for `$file`.

Comment: I was having a look at possible solutions and methods others had used to do similar tasks. Even without the brackets, it doesn't create the row at all, hmm.

Comment: Seem to have fixed the problem now! Thank you for assistance :).